# Assets image to Internal storage runtime

Tags: android, html

I have converted docx to html and able to display it in webview with images. However, when I try saving the html extracted from webview to internal storage the images are not visible and are rather leaving a blank space in the saved html file.

The code for doing this as follows:

```
view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webpage);

    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final long endTime;
    try {
        final LoadFromZipNG loader = new LoadFromZipNG();
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = (WordprocessingMLPackage)loader.get(new FileInputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+getIntent().getStringExtra("textReportFileName"))));

        String IMAGE_DIR_NAME = "images";

        String baseURL = this.getDir(IMAGE_DIR_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE).toURL().toString();
        System.out.println(baseURL); // file:/data/data/com.example.HelloAndroid/app_images/

        // Uncomment this to write image files to file system
        ConversionImageHandler conversionImageHandler = new AndroidFileConversionImageHandler( IMAGE_DIR_NAME, // <-- don't use a path separator here
                baseURL, false, this);
```

> Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),baseURL,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

```
        HtmlExporterNonXSLT withoutXSLT = new HtmlExporterNonXSLT(wordMLPackage, conversionImageHandler);

        html = XmlUtils.w3CDomNodeToString(withoutXSLT.export());

        File filex = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/temp/"+getIntent().getStringExtra("textReportFileName").replace("docx","html"));
        if(filex.exists()) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            InputStream iss = new FileInputStream(filex);
            int size = iss.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            iss.read(buffer);
            iss.close();

            html = new String(buffer);
            //html = html.substring(html.indexOf("0\" rows=\"9\">") + 16);
        }
        else{

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    } finally {
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
```

The highlighted toast message gives the output : file:/data/data/com.tek.teksmartlab/app_images/

Also the final html file has the image tags with the src = "file:/data/data/com.tek.teksmartlab/app_images/image1.jpg" (like form)

Now I understand the path file:/data/data/com.tek.teksmartlab/app_images/ is non existent in the internal storage so `HOW DO I SAVE THE IMAGES FROM THIS PATH TO INTERNAL STORAGE??`

I have tried copying the image from assets folder to internal storage code but that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `url` is not complete you need it to start with `file://` so the whole thing would be

```
file:///data/data/com.tek.teksmartlab/app_images/image1.jpg
```

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't resolve the issue as well because the file:/// will basically check the assets of the app which in my case is HTML Viewer. Thus we need to extract the images and store them in some internal storage. How do we do that? As I said I have already checked codes online and it doesn't help.